Probability that two random triangles in 3-space link each other
Let $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, and $F$ be points on the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ in $3$-space chosen independently from the uniform distribution on $\mathbb{S}^2$. What is the probability that triangle $ABC$ links triangle $DEF$?.
Alternatively, let $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, and $F$ be points of $3$-space chosen independently from the standard normal distribution on $3$-space, and then ask the same question.
Two simple closed curves in $3$-space link if they are disjoint and if every topological $2$-dimensional disk in $3$-space whose boundary equals either one of the curves necessarily intersects the other one.
A more refined notion, originally defined by Gauss, is the linking number of two disjoint oriented simple closed curves in $3$-space. This is an integer that tells something about how the two curves are linked. That number can even be $0$ despite the two curves being linked.
But for two disjoint triangles that actually link, the linking number can be only $\pm 1$. For two disjoint triangles that don't link, the linking number must be $0$. Gauss described an integration formula for the linking number, discussed in this article.

I assume "on the unit sphere" means on its surface, yes?

What does it mean for triangles to link? They intersect?

The unit sphere is S = {(x,y,z) ∈ R^3  |  x^2 + y^2 + z^2  =  1}.

As for linking, two 1-dimensional triangles link if the 2-dimensional triangle ∆ spanning either one of them intersects the other 1-dimensional triangle T in exactly one point, such that T lies on both sides of ∆. (Alternatively, they are linked if when each triangle undergoes its own rigid motion in 3-space, the two triangles cannot be moved arbitrarily far apart without intersecting at some stage of the motion.)

Given that "linking" seems to be your own definition (EG A google search doesn't show up any result), I'd encourage you to 1/ move the comment into the problem, and 2/ provide a lot more details and examples. EG What is a 1-dimensional triangle? 3 points that are concurrent?

Linking is a standard concept in topology. My definition appears unusual only because it is tailored for triangles. But I will incorporate a definition in the question.

@DanA So — basically — we have to decide the probability that two affine planes $n_1\cdot x=a_1$ and $n_2\cdot x=a_2$ (with $|a_i|\le 1$ and $|n_i|=1$) intersect inside the unit sphere.

TedS — I haven't seen such a reduction of linking to your condition — which I can't say I fully understand yet — before, so will have to think about why what you are saying. (I have a different algorithm to determine linking.)

That's exactly why I wasn't sure of the meaning.

Ah, OK, sorry for the miscue. Indeed, it’s now obviously wrong. I’ll think more …
